# IntelliJ can't find my Grails install

Tags: grails, configuration, module, intellij-14

Im still using IntelliJ 14 (can't afford the upgrade) but now Im working on a Grails project. I used `sdkman` to install Groovy and Grails so my Grails install is in the usual place (i.e. `/Users/whoever/.sdkman/candidates/grails/current`). I see console messages telling me that IntelliJ is trying to find `release-2.2.0.zip` (which doesn't exist anywhere locally AFAIK). Also see attempts to connect to `mvn.quonb.org` which all fail. Is there a new repo? Can I tell IntelliJ to look somewhere else? How to fix?